# xslt sum and round syntax help needed

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to pull and sum hours per person in the main body of my xslt and then also sum the hours in the trailer.  The trailer sum total and the body sum totals do not match, they are off by .01 (due to rounding I assume?).  I am not sure what the correct syntax should be to make both pieces equal the same sum of hours.  I've searched but can't quite find what I'm looking for, any help or guidance is appreciated!

**Here is my body xslt - this returns 37420050 = 374,200.50:**

template match="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry"

xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours) * 100,'0000000000;-000000000')"

**Here is my trailer xslt - this returns a total of 37420049 - 374,200.49:**

xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours) * 100,'0000000000;-000000000')"

Thanks,
Jenn

Comment: This is not a [mcve] which is required by SO. So it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you have the option of using decimal arithmetic rather than floating point. This is not possible in XSLT 1.0. To use decimal arithmetic, cast the operands of the multiplication to `xs:decimal`, e.g.

```
 sum(wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours)/xs:decimal() * 100)
```

Even with decimal arithmetic, the `format-number()` function may do some rounding which can lead to numbers not adding up to 100%. You may need to check whether there are conventions or accountancy regulations that constrain how you address this problem.